# How can I change the min and max value of vertical axis in chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, microsoft-excel

I want the vertical axis to range between 75 and 125. The min should be 75 and the max should be 125.

0 to 125 range is automatically generated.

The highest data point is 107 and the lowest data point is 80.

Do you know how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Edit the chart
- Select "Customize"
- Select "Vertical Axis"
- Where it says "Min" and "Max", enter the desired minimum and maximum axis
- Close the Chart Editor

---

[image: chart]